# Change Excel Circular Dependency into PHP

Tags: php, excel

I deleted a question I posted earlier because I oversimplified the example, and got more flak for problems there, so have decided to post the whole problem here instead.

**The Task**

Much like this question here...[Copying Excel's Circular Reference formula in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213537/copying-excels-circular-reference-formula-in-php) I am trying to change an Excel Circular reference into PHP.

Most of my frustration is not knowing the correct terms to google this for myself.

**The Situation**

I have converted all logic in the following spreadsheet into PHP below...

[image]

```
<?php

$vat = '1.2';
$mileage = 10;
$price = 6250.00;
$contract_term = 24;
$deposit_months = 6;
$otr_price = 9409.00;
$discount = 0;
$lom_a = 36.08;
$lom_b = 5.14;
$vehicletype = "Car";
$first_reg_fee = 55.00;
$emission_price = 30.00;
$fees = 21.03;
$margin = 50.00;


if (!empty($discount)) {
  $discounted_otr_percent = (int)$discount/100;
  $discounted_otr_amount = $discounted_otr_percent * $otr_price;
  $discounted_otr = $otr_price-$discounted_otr_amount;
} else {
  $discounted_otr = $otr_price;
}


$totaltobefunded = ($discounted_otr - $first_reg_fee - 0 /* Emissions */) / $vat;
print '<hr><p>Total to be Funded: <strong>' . $totaltobefunded . '</strong></p>';

$vatbal = $discounted_otr - $first_reg_fee - 0 /* Emissions */ - $totaltobefunded;
print '<p>VAT: <strong>' . $vatbal . '</strong></p>';


if($vehicletype == "Car") {
    $balloon = $price / $vat  * 0.9;
} else {
    $balloon = $price * 0.9;
}
print '<p>CAP 90% price: <strong>' . $balloon . '</strong></p>';


$totalamountborrowed = $totaltobefunded - $balloon;
print '<p>Total Amount Borrowed: <strong>' . $totalamountborrowed . '</strong></p>';


$fundingrental = $totalamountborrowed * $lom_a / 1000;
print '<p>Funding Rental: <strong>' . $fundingrental . '</strong></p>';


$balloonrental = $balloon * $lom_b / 1000;
print '<p>Funding Rental: <strong>' . $balloonrental . '</strong></p>';


$monthlyfinancerental = $fundingrental + $balloonrental;
print '<p>Monthly Finance Rental: <strong>' . $monthlyfinancerental . '</strong></p>';


$monthlyrentalwithfees = $monthlyfinancerental + $fees;
print '<p>Monthly Finance Rental With Fees: <strong>' . $monthlyrentalwithfees . '</strong></p>';


$totalmargin = $margin * $contract_term;
print '<p>Total Margin: <strong>' . $totalmargin . '</strong></p>';


$totalrentalandfees = $monthlyrentalwithfees * ($contract_term + $deposit_months -1);
print '<p>Total Rental and Fees: <strong>' . $totalrentalandfees . '</strong></p>';

$totalcontractcost = $totalmargin + $totalrentalandfees;
print '<p>Total Contract Cost: <strong>' . $totalcontractcost . '</strong></p>';


$actualmonthlyrental = $totalcontractcost / ($contract_term + $deposit_months -1);
print '<p>Actual Monthly Rental: <strong>' . $actualmonthlyrental . '</strong></p>';


$deposit = $actualmonthlyrental * $deposit_months;
print '<p>Deposit: <strong>' . $deposit . '</strong></p>';
```

In the PHP code above, I have hard coded all of the variables for the time being just to get this working. In the real life example, these will change for each vehicle.

A Circular Reference exists between **N19** (Total to be funded) , **N34** (Actual Monthly Rental) and **N36** (Deposit).

So at some point before, during, or after the FOR statement, there needs to be...

```
$totaltobefunded = $totaltobefunded - $deposit;
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried using the PHP for from the linked question on my example, but it just keeps taking away the deposit from the Total to be funded, and I am left with minus numbers.

In the example in the link, it has the following results...

> 1410
>
> 1211.19
>
> 1239.22221
>
> 1235.26966839
>
> 1235.826976757
>
> 1235.7483962773
>
> 1235.7594761249
>
> 1235.7579138664
>
> 1235.7581341448
>
> 1235.7581030856
>
> 1235.7581074649
>
> 1235.7581068474

This refines the number to the best possible outcome, and this is what I am trying to achieve. Just like my Excel document.

At the moment, my PHP prints out....

> Total to be Funded: 7795
>
> VAT: 1559
>
> CAP 90% price: 4687.5
>
> Total Amount Borrowed: 3107.5
>
> Funding Rental: 112.1186
>
> Funding Rental: 24.09375
>
> Monthly Finance Rental: 136.21235
>
> Monthly Finance Rental With Fees: 157.24235
>
> Total Margin: 1200
>
> Total Rental and Fees: 4560.02815
>
> Total Contract Cost: 5760.02815
>
> Actual Monthly Rental: 198.62166034483
>
> Deposit: 1191.729962069

**What I need help with**

Using the PHP code above (which I have over simplified for this question btw), where should I put my "for" statement in order to correctly loop through the 3 numbers in the circular reference to get the result Im after?

As you can see in the Excel Screenshot, the target numbers are...

> Total to be Funded: 6815.32
>
> VAT: 2538.68
>
> CAP 90% price: 4687.5
>
> Total Amount Borrowed: 2127.82
>
> Funding Rental: 76.7717456
>
> Funding Rental: 24.09375
>
> Monthly Finance Rental: 100.8654956
>
> Monthly Finance Rental With Fees: 121.8954956
>
> Total Margin: 1200
>
> Total Rental and Fees: 3534.9693724
>
> Total Contract Cost: 4734.9693724
>
> Actual Monthly Rental: 163.27480594483
>
> Deposit: 979.64883566897

I hope this makes sense to someone and they can assist. I'll answer any questions as best as I can.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in PHP is as follows....

```
<?php
    $vat = '1.2';
    $mileage = 10;
    $price = 6250.00;
    $contract_term = 24;
    $deposit_months = 6;
    $otr_price = 9409.00;
    $discount = 0;
    $lom_a = 36.08;
    $lom_b = 5.14;
    $vehicletype = "Car";
    $first_reg_fee = 55.00;
    $emission_price = 30.00;
    $fees = 21.03;
    $margin = 50.00;
    $deposit = 0;

    if (!empty($discount)) {
      $discounted_otr_percent = (int)$discount/100;
      $discounted_otr_amount = $discounted_otr_percent * $otr_price;
      $discounted_otr = $otr_price-$discounted_otr_amount;
    } else {
      $discounted_otr = $otr_price;
    }
    $max_iter = 100;
    $max_change = 0.001;
    $prev_target_val = PHP_INT_MAX;
    $totaltobefunded = 0;
    $crt_iter = 0;
    while(($crt_iter < $max_iter) && (abs($prev_target_val - $totaltobefunded) > $max_change)) {
        $crt_iter++;
        $prev_target_val = $totaltobefunded;
    $totaltobefunded = ($discounted_otr - $first_reg_fee - 0 /* Emissions */) / $vat - $deposit;
    $vatbal = $discounted_otr - $first_reg_fee - 0 /* Emissions */ - $totaltobefunded;
    if($vehicletype == "Car") {
        $balloon = $price / $vat  * 0.9;
    } else {
        $balloon = $price * 0.9;
    }
    $totalamountborrowed = $totaltobefunded - $balloon;
    $fundingrental = $totalamountborrowed * $lom_a / 1000;
    $balloonrental = $balloon * $lom_b / 1000;
    $monthlyfinancerental = $fundingrental + $balloonrental;
    $monthlyrentalwithfees = $monthlyfinancerental + $fees;
    $totalmargin = $margin * $contract_term;
    $totalrentalandfees = $monthlyrentalwithfees * ($contract_term + $deposit_months -1);
    $totalcontractcost = $totalmargin + $totalrentalandfees;
    $actualmonthlyrental = $totalcontractcost / ($contract_term + $deposit_months -1);
    $deposit = $actualmonthlyrental * $deposit_months;
    }
    print '<p>Final Number: <strong>' . $actualmonthlyrental . '</strong></p>';
    ?>
```